# Could not resolve placeholder in string value

Tags: java, xml, spring, placeholder, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to use properties from a .properties file, but it desn't work. 
I'm getting this error:

```
2017-03-03 11:33:22,893 [localhost-startStop-1] []                                ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Invalid bean definition with name 'sessionFactoryInit' 
defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/dev/Escale/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/hx_u4WebServices/WEB-INF/lib/hx_u4Persistence.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext-hibernate-init.xml]: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'ipon.hibernate.show_sql' in string value "${ipon.hibernate.show_sql}"
```

Can you help me please ?

applicationContext-hibernate-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

        <bean id="sessionFactoryInit" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" abstract="true">
            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop 

key="hibernate.dialect">fr.laposte.courrier.escale.ipon.persistence.dialect.SpecificOracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${ipon.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${ipon.hibernate.max_fetch_depth}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">${ipon.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${ipon.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>       
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${ipon.hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

C:\dev\Escale\u4\Sources\livraison\conf\IPON\config\ipon.properties

```
ipon.hibernate.show_sql = false
ipon.hibernate.max_fetch_depth = 3
ipon.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size = 500
ipon.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 40
ipon.hibernate.generate_statistics = false

ipon.c3p0.acquireIncrement =  2
ipon.c3p0.initialPoolSize = 60
ipon.c3p0.maxPoolSize = 200
ipon.c3p0.minPoolSize = 40
ipon.c3p0.maxIdleTime = 300 
ipon.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod = 20
ipon.c3p0.maxStatements = 50

ipon.rechercheClient.limitation = 60
ipon.rechercheCommande.limitation = 60

# en secondes
ipon.session.timeout = 7200
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>iponServices</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>iponServices.root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>logbackConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file:${IPONN}/config/log.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

VM Arguments in tomcat 7 (eclipse)
[Vm argument Tomcat 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Jmn.png)

-DIPONN="C:/dev/Escale/u4/Sources/livraison/conf/IPON"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the property placeholder bean in your context :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>file:${IPONN}/config/ipon.properties</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can add it in your applicationContext-hibernate-config.xml